# Query post and post type with a template-part for each

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type

How can I load post and post type (named "Projets") using différent template-parts for each one of them ? Here My query is loading post and post type, but both of them have the same design in the end.
Thank you !

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    ?>

    <?php
    while ($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();

        ?>
        <?php  get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'content');?>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not checked but it supposed to work

In order to get current `post_type` while in the loop use:

```
if ( 'the_post_type_here' == get_post_type() ){ code... }
```

so your code shoud go like:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
?>

<?php
while ($query->have_posts())
{
    $query->the_post();

    ?>
    <?php
       if ( 'Projets' == get_post_type() ){
        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'content');
       }
    ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```